# Start windows service on install without setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, setup-project, autostart

I have developed a windows service, but need it to start automatically on install. Problem is that every tutorial I found is showing me through the `Setup Project`. There is a fantastic 3 part tutorial [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2aFNtcZfk&src_vid=EwTYYPRcWj0&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_462730) that I used to convert my app to a service, but I don't have the `Setup Project` in my other project types. Can I do this programatically or is there a way I can get the `Setup Project` project type?

Comment: how do you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Installer class, add a handler for the AfterInstall event. You can then call the ServiceController in the event handler to start the service.

```
public ServiceInstaller()
{
    //... Installer code here
    this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall);
}

void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName))
    {
         sc.Start();
    }
}
```

Now when you run InstallUtil on your installer it will install and then start up the service.

[MSDN link for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) project has built-in service Installer/Uninstaller. when integrated in the application, it can be installed as a service through simple command from application itself, for example we can easily install and start `myService.exe` with `myService.exe install start` command.

we can simply create a self installing service, here is an Example:

```
    public class ServiceClass
    {
        public ServiceClass()
        {
        }
        public void Start() {  }
        public void Stop() {  }
    }

public class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        //we can simply install our service by setting specific commands for same or install it directly from command line or from another process
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
            var install = Process.Start(processName, "install start");
            install.WaitForExit();
            return;
        }

        HostFactory.Run(x =>          
        {
            x.Service<ServiceClass>(s =>            
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new ServiceClass()); 
                s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());        
                s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());         
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();                     

            x.SetDescription("Topshelf Host");       
            x.SetDisplayName("TopShelf");               
            x.SetServiceName("TopShelf");                 
        });                                       
    }
}
```

you can get Topshelf through `PM> Install-Package Topshelf` Nuget command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Windows 7 and up, Powershell is installed by default. One option is to run a simple powershell script which installs the service, starts it, and sets the service to start automatically if the machine is rebooted:

```
InstallUtil yourService.exe
Start-Service yourService
Set-Service yourService -startuptype "Automatic"
```

Comment: If you want to ask questions, please use a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Noel I am targeting windows, I believe 7, and I am trying to avoid our network people having to remember to start the service initially on server reboots. I could easily run the `InstallUtil app.exe` command on server cycling, but that's what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to add on the Installer Projects Extension!

The Setup project type was deprecated after VS 2010, but following feedback Microsoft have brought back a new version for VS 2013.

Install the new Installer Projects Extension from Microsoft: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

This should work for any non-express version of Visual Studio 2013 (including the new free Community Edition SDK)

Then you can just follow the same instructions as for the VS 2010 setup projects :)

There isn't an easy option for VS2012 (you could try an installer with WiX I guess, but thats a lot to learn!) 
I'm not sure if InstallShield LE (free version for VS2012) would work for this situation, but you could give it a try.

You can always change the startup type of a service after installation remember. (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services -> right click service -> Properties -> change "Startup Type" to "Automatic" )

Comment: Crud. Thought that was the solution, I am on VS2012. I have updated the tags to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm. Time for an upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see that happening with this company. >.<

Comment: Well if the company is below $1M annual turnover or < 250 pcs you're still eligible for the new (free) Community Edition of VS 2013. If its more than that then TBH a VS2013 upgrade should be a tiny and worthwhile cost! Either that, or waste loads of time on a Wix or InstallShield installer (or just change start-up type post install as per my edited answer)

Comment: Yeah, it's WAY over the $1M mark, might attempt talking them into an upgrade, but this year has been a beast on the budget due to some already major upgrades. I might try to do the after install change. If that will cause the service to run on windows startup that should actually solve my issue though.

Comment: yeah it will. I would have thought VS2013 would be easy enough to justify based on the productivity enhancements alone ("Peek Definition" for one!) However I suppose VS 2015 is just around the corner now.